# How do I input an icon in the navigation menu and make it hover sub menus?

Tags: html, css, navigation, icons, nav

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I could implement icons into my navigation menu, can't find a proper tutorial for this. What I'm trying to is making something similar to this -

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJiCt.jpg "navigation example (before hover and after)"

How can I put icons with text (or a complete image icon) instead of the normal li text ?

Appreciate it.

Comment: You can use sprites, or transparent png image, or even icon font. Just search about these terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial for you.

http://www.ehousestudio.com/blog/view/css_sprite_navigation_tutorial